# Resolving a Dependency Cycle

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent

I've been having a lot of fun rigging, but I've run into a problem. I have knowingly created a Dependency cycle, thinking it wouldn't be problem. It kinda works, but weird bugs appear sometimes, and my system console gets spammed with Dependency cycle detections :/

In this excample I have two bones. One the parent of another. (The parent is on the right)

[image]

now, using a transformation constraint, the parent bone is supposed to rotate and move upwards when the child bone gets rotated to the left:

[image]

This is obviously the cause of the dependancy loop, but I don't see any way to resolve it.
The child bone has to follow the rotation of the parent, even if that rotation is indirectly caused by the child itself.

edit:
let's say I'm making a mailbox. The child is the door, and the parent is the rest.

[image]

When the door opens, the entire mailbox should rise up slightly:

[image]

So, the child bone is what I use to control the door, and I can't simply use the paerent bone :(. Hope that makes it more clear.. thanks :)

Comment: it looks like the solution you've chosen is not the good one, maybe describe more precisely what you want to achieve so that someone propose a more adequate solution

Comment: Why can't you directly rotate the parent? You can always display it at the position of the child so it would appear as if it were the child.

Comment: @moonboots I've edited my post and I really hope that helps with the explanation..

Comment: @Leander I've edited my post and I really hope that helps with the explanation..

Comment: You create a new, independent control bone for both bones, that is unparented to either, from which the others copy rotation.  Then, you only touch your new control bone.

Answer (score 1):

So what about the other way around, parenting the door bone to the box bone, and give a *Transformation* constraint to the door bone so that when you rotate the box bone it makes the door follow (as it is parented) and rotate (with the constraint)? You can also limit the rotation of the box for more comfort.

Unless you have a good reason to manipulate the door bone only?

[image]